# Sublime Text 3 highlight matches with #

Tags: sublimetext3, settings, syntax-highlighting, highlight, separator

I'm using Sublime Text 3.2.2, and I really enjoy this feature:

```
  // Highlights other occurrences of the currently selected text
        "match_selection": true,
```

But there's a situation where this feature doesn't work for me - It's when my string has the # character:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
TEST #TEST #
TEST #TEST
123  #123 123 #123
TEST #TEST #
```

Could you test please? Have you ever noticed that? Can we adjust this?

OBS:

my word separators for this syntax: `` "word_separators": "~!$%^&*|+=`~,()[]{}" ``

The same seems to occur with the `?` character

Comment: Several people have reproduced this behavior. It's not just you. You could [file a bug report](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/new?template=bug_report.md) on GitHub.

Comment: Ok, done. Issue  #3525

Comment: [Direct link](https://github.com/sublimehq/sublime_text/issues/3525) to the bug report, in case it's helpful to future visitors.